# TextInputLayout suffix/prefix

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I want to add suffix to TextInputLayout.
An example is taken from the [material.io](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-input-types)

[image: Example]

Are there any standard solutions?

Comment: Won't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37278154/1083957) be helpful to you?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md) provided in the Material Components Library you can use the attrs:

- **`app:prefixText`**: prefix text
- **`app:suffixText`**: suffix text

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:hint="Test"
    app:prefixText="@string/..."
    app:prefixTextColor="@color/secondaryDarkColor"
    app:suffixText="@string/..."
    app:suffixTextColor="@color/primaryLightColor"
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Example:

[image]

**Note:** This requires a minimum of version **`1.2.0-alpha01`**.

Comment: When I try this the floating label for the hint ("Test" in the Example image) is moved out to the end of the prefix. Do you know any way to avoid this, so it can work like the Example image

Comment: @Gober It is quite strange. Post a question with all details.

Comment: Posted question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101279/how-to-change-hint-padding-for-textinputlayout-when-using-the-new-prefixtext @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: The prefix is visible no doubt, but the alignment is quite off between the prefix and text. : (

Comment: How to add padding between prefix and text?

Comment: @iCantC you can use app:prefixTextAppearance to align prefix and text.

Comment: @YellowJ custom or existing TextAppearance like app:prefixTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"

Answer (score 6):

There are no standard solutions, I did it with textView right to textInputLayout and editText padding.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Hint"
                app:errorEnabled="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    style="@style/RegistrationEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="80dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:text="rightLabel" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is no need to use AppCompatTextView because it gets automatically inflated when you use TextView