# How to change hint padding for TextInputLayout when using the new prefixText?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I have tried implementing `TextInputLayout` with the new `prefixText`, using `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02`. This is a very cool feature, but when I add a prefix text the hint label floats up and aligns after the prefix. This does not look good, especially if you have more input fields on the same page without prefix, the floating labels does not align.

[image: screenshot]

Relevant parts of my layout code:

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/login_input_fields"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_username_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        app:prefixText="Prefix">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_username_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_password_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'am not able to reproduce the issue with 1.2.0-alpha02

Comment: That is very strange Gabriele. Could there be other dependencies or something else affecting this. I am also using 1.2.0-alpha02

Comment: Do you change something like `gravity` programmatically? Or do you have a custom style defined with the `textInputStyle` attr in your app theme?

Comment: Now I tried creating a brand new project in Android Studio with the Blank Activity template. Added the layout code above and material:1.2.0-alpha02 and was able to reproduce it even in the Preview window (you must add text to the TextInputEditText for the hint label to float up)

Comment: Ok I am able to replicate. It depends by the wrong theme used in the app. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the Material Components Library you **have to use** a [**`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`** theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).

Using your layout with this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
 ...
</style>
```

[image]

Using your layout with this theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
  ...
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 val prefixView = textInputLayout.findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.textinput_prefix_text)
  prefixView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
  prefixView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

you may find more details here  https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/773
if you wish to light prefix with input text