# Android TextInputLayout prefix/suffix text not appear even after upgrade to 1.2.0-alpha01

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I try to implement prefix/suffix text after upgrade to `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01` but it doesn't work, prefix/suffix text is not appear is there any solution or should i upgrade another dependencies?

here some code snippet

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:prefixText="$">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Just have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262272/textinputlayout-suffix-prefix :)

Comment: It does appear when you tap on TextInputEditText field.