# Support RTL for custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, android-edittext, android-custom-view

I'm creating a [custom `EditText`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278154/8583692) to append a suffix to the text with the following code:

```java
public class EditTextWithSuffix extends AppCompatEditText {

    TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
    private String suffix = "ssssss";

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        int suffixXPosition = (int) textPaint.measureText(getText().toString()) + getPaddingLeft();
        c.drawText(suffix, suffixXPosition, getBaseline(), textPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }
}
```

The suffix (`ssssss`) is correctly shown in input field for Left-to-Right langs such as English but not for RTL layouts (like Arabic or Persian).

Would you please help?

Comment: Does the suffix need to be retrievable or just visually there?

Comment: @Ge3ng I just want it to be shown and do not need to retrieve it.

Comment: You could use a TextWatcher to see changes and then modify the text to append the suffix. It is much easier than making a custom view.

Comment: I don't want to use a text watcher.